# How to convert a list of values from a dictionary to string?

Tags: python

This solution does not seem to work, I fall back on integers, is there a solution without using map()?

```py
dictionary = {"first":[1, 2, 3], 
              "second":[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}

d = {k: map(str, v) for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

Expect output:

```py
dictionary = {"first":['1', '2', '3'], 
              "second":['4', '5', '6', '7', '8']}
```

Comment: `d = {k: [str(i) for i in v] for k, v in dictionary.items()}`

Comment: In Python 3+ `d = {k: list(map(str, v)) for k,v in dictionary.items()}`

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320175/how-to-convert-integers-in-list-to-string-in-python

Comment: Thanks a lot! I open a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689615/how-to-transform-the-first-item-of-the-list-of-values-of-a-dictionary) linked to this one which also causes me problems.

Answer (score 0):

```py
dictionary = {"first":[1, 2, 3], 
              "second":[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}

d = {k: list(map(str, v)) for k,v in dictionary.items()}
print(d)
```

This will provide the required output.as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001592/dani-mesejo

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with creating an answer that matches someone's comment but it's at least appropriate to attribute it to them, if for no other reason than they said it first. Otherwise, it looks like taking their solution as your own.