# How to transform the first item of the list of values of a dictionary?

Tags: python

Simply a similar question here in relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689464/how-to-convert-a-list-of-values-from-a-dictionary-to-string) question which also causes me problems, what if I want to transform into a string only the first item of the values of lists for example?

```py
dictionary = {"first":[1, 2, 3], 
              "second":[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Expect output:

```py
dictionary = {"first":['1', 2, 3], 
              "second":['4', 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the values of the dictionary and replace the first element with its corresponding string value. Try this:

```
for v in dictionary.values():
   v[0] = str(v[0])
```

The output:

```
{'first': ['1', 2, 3], 'second': ['4', 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over all the items in `dictionary` and change each item to a string:

```
for i in dictionary:
    dictionary[i][0] = str(dictionary[i][0])
```

Output:

```
{'first': ['1', 2, 3], 'second': ['4', 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```